# Saving a user created point or polygon [Google Maps API]

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables, google-sheets-api

I am currently creating a tool which utilises google maps - specifically user-made polygons and points. I understand how to load/create points/polygons from the script, but I do not understand how/if it is possible for the user to generate a custom point/polygon and then have it saved.

It is clearly possible as sites like http://www.cycle-route.com utilise this concept.

I was wondering if anyone can help me out?

Comment: One option would be to use something like [blitz-gmap-editor](http://code.google.com/p/blitz-gmap-editor/) and a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two tables. One for polygon and the other for points. Fields in points table can be lat, lon, polygon_id and order(from the polygon created). Google maps polygon will give all the details.

```
var vertices = polygon.getPath();
var polygonPoints = [];
for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
    polygonPoints.push({ lat: xy.lat(), lon: xy.lng() });
}
return polygonPoints;

//polygonPoints will be the array and index of the array will be the order
```

Create an array of points (sort according to order) , pass it to google.maps.Polygon and you can recreate the polygon(if u want)

Comment: is it also possible with multiple shapes drawn on the map?